Power bi FILTER,ALLSELECTED,VALUES why?
Toplam Miktar Taze = 
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'DB'[Brut] ),
    FILTER (
        ALLSELECTED ( 'DB' ),
        'DB'[KG]
            IN { "10 KG-S", "10 KG-U", "6 KG-S" }
                && 'DB'[Tip]  = "Taze"
    ),VALUES('DB'[Tip])
)

When I use the code in this way, it returns the result as shown below.

I just want the lines 10 KG-S, 10 KG-U, and 6 KG-S to come.

pls try this
MEASURE =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( 'Table'[Miktart] ),
    FILTER (
        'Table',
        'Table'[KG]
            IN { "10 KG-S", "10 KG-U", "6 KG-S" }
                && 'Table'[Tip] = "Taze"
    )
)

or
Measure2 =
IF (
    MAX ( 'Table'[KG] )
        IN { "10 KG-S", "10 KG-U", "6 KG-S" }
            && MAX ( 'Table'[Tip] ) = "Taze",
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( 'Table'[Miktart] ),
        FILTER (
            ALL ( 'Table' ),
            'Table'[KG]
                IN { "10 KG-S", "10 KG-U", "6 KG-S" }
                    && 'Table'[Tip] = "Taze"
        )
    )
)


